# Confusion regarding question came in my today's exam

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, notation

G(d) was determined to be $3d+c$, here c is :

1. Constant of differentiation

2.Constant of anti differentiation

3.constant of integartion

4.constant of death and taxes

I chose option 3. But i am confused between option 3 and 2. Is this question even right?

Thanks

Comment: I like the $4$th choice the best.

Comment: I guess you _could_ call it "the constant of anti-differentiation": other mathematicians will understand what you mean, but they will just think you're a bit weird, or that your English skills aren't very good. It's important to communicate clearly in mathematics, so using non-standard terms is  counter-productive. BTW, using $d$ as a variable name in a calculus problem is evil.

Answer (score 1):

$$G(d) = 3d + c$$

Hence

$$G'(d) = 3$$

Which means that $c$ can be, in this case, a constant of integration.

To me it's ok.

The "anti differentiation" is the process to get the anti derivative, so it's ok number $3$ to me.

Comment: any proof to deny option  (2)

Comment: @ketan I admit I thought about that. I wonder if it's just about.. semantic...