# is constant of integration also constant of Anti-Differentiation?

Tags: calculus, integration

i have thought integration to be same as anti-differentiation. So the constant we add after integration should be called constant of anti differentiation.
for example, in question below, i know option 2 is right but i marked option 1 in my exam, thinking they are similar.

G(d) was determined to be 3d+c, here c is :

1.Constant of anti differentiation

2.constant of integration

I need to proper arguments to prove that option 1 can also be correct.please help.

Comment: There is nothing called *constant of antidifferentiation* in Mathematics.Search the Wikipedia instead

Comment: See this [related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022784/confusion-regarding-question-came-in-my-todays-exam).

Comment: @C. Falcon ya i comented there too..

Comment: Indeed! I didn't see it was you in the comments! :)

Comment: i see sophie was in same exam. still can we have any argument in favour of option1 here?

Comment: Which exam is this ?@ketan;Why are so many here participating in that exam

Comment: I really don't know the answer. In France we do not really care about the name of our constants, but as pointed by learnmore, *constant of anti-differentiation* is not referenced on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a waste of time to argue.  You didn't know the proper terminology.  If you had made up all your own math notation so that no one else could read it, you'd be in the same boat.  Part of learning math is to learn how to express it.

That said, "constant of integration" is better.  Because sometimes these constants appear when no anti-derivative has been computed.  E.g., in the differential equations $y''-4y=0$, the usual way of solving produces $y = c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{-2t}.$  What function did you take the anti-derivative of?  Yet there are two constants of integration.  Integration (the pasting together of differentiated functions) can happen without anti-differentiation (the mechanical inversion of the differentiation operation.)